# Why does if Assigned(ListViewLayers1.Items) then Produce an Exception

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

```
{ Clear ListViewLayers }
  try
    if Assigned(ListViewLayers1.Items) then
      ListViewLayers1.Clear;
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      ShowMessage(E.ClassName + #10#13 + E.Message);
    end;
  end;
```

How can you determine if the listview is empty before trying to call Clear?

The Exception is EAccessViolation.  But I do not understand why when the ListViewLayers1 was created at design time and can be accessed at other times throughout the life of the app.

```
EurekaLog 7.0.7.1  

Exception:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  2.2 Address: 00D2E79E
  2.5 Type   : EAccessViolation
  2.6 Message: Access violation at address 00D2E79E in module 'FaceBookDesigner.exe'. Read of address 00000000
  2.7 ID     : 20970000
  2.11 Sent  : 0

User:
-------------------------
  3.2 Name : Windows User
  3.3 Email: 

Steps to reproduce:
------------
  8.1 Text: 


Call Stack Information:
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Methods |Details|Stack   |Address |Module              |Offset  |Unit            |Class              |Procedure/Method                          |Line      |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|*Exception Thread: ID=10000; Parent=0; Priority=0                                                                                                          |
|Class=; Name=MAIN                                                                                                                                          |
|DeadLock=0; Wait Chain=                                                                                                                                    |
|Comment=                                                                                                                                                   |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Processes Information:
----------------------


Assembler Information:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Base Address: $D2E000, Allocation Base: $400000, Region Size: 94208
; Allocation Protect: PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY, Protect: PAGE_EXECUTE_READ
; State: MEM_COMMIT, Type: MEM_IMAGE
; 
;
; Unit1.TForm1.UpdateGUI (Line=1803 - Offset=8)
; ---------------------------------------------
00D2E738  8B45FC        MOV  EAX, [EBP-4]
00D2E73B  8B80A0030000  MOV  EAX, [EAX+$000003A0]
00D2E741  8B90D0060000  MOV  EDX, [EAX+$000006D0]
00D2E747  8B45FC        MOV  EAX, [EBP-4]
00D2E74A  8B80A0030000  MOV  EAX, [EAX+$000003A0]
00D2E750  E86FBEE6FF    CALL -$194191                   ; ($00B9A5C4) imageenview.TImageEnView.GetLayer
00D2E755  8B8080000000  MOV  EAX, [EAX+$00000080]
00D2E75B  BA20EAD200    MOV  EDX, $00D2EA20             ; ($00D2EA20) Unit1.TForm1.UpdateGUI (Line=1829) ANSI: 'Border'
00D2E760  E81FD26DFF    CALL -$922DE1                   ; ($0040B984) System._LStrEqual
00D2E765  7518          JNZ  +$18                       ; ($00D2E77F) Unit1.TForm1.UpdateGUI (Line=1806)
;
; Line=1804 - Offset=55
; ---------------------
00D2E767  BA34EAD200    MOV  EDX, $00D2EA34             ; ($00D2EA34) Unit1.TForm1.UpdateGUI (Line=1829) UNICODE: 'Replace'
00D2E76C  8B45FC        MOV  EAX, [EBP-4]
00D2E76F  8B8018040000  MOV  EAX, [EAX+$00000418]
00D2E775  8B08          MOV  ECX, [EAX]
00D2E777  FF9120010000  CALL DWORD PTR [ECX+$00000120]
00D2E77D  EB16          JMP  +$16                       ; ($00D2E795) Unit1.TForm1.UpdateGUI (Line=1808)
;
; Line=1806 - Offset=79
; ---------------------
00D2E77F  BA50EAD200    MOV  EDX, $00D2EA50             ; ($00D2EA50) Unit1.TForm1.UpdateGUI (Line=1829) UNICODE: 'Border'
00D2E784  8B45FC        MOV  EAX, [EBP-4]
00D2E787  8B8018040000  MOV  EAX, [EAX+$00000418]
00D2E78D  8B08          MOV  ECX, [EAX]
00D2E78F  FF9120010000  CALL DWORD PTR [ECX+$00000120]
;
; Line=1808 - Offset=101
; ----------------------
00D2E795  8B45FC        MOV  EAX, [EBP-4]
00D2E798  8B80B0030000  MOV  EAX, [EAX+$000003B0]
;
; Line=1808 - Offset=110
; ----------------------
00D2E79E  8B10          MOV  EDX, [EAX]                 ; <-- EXCEPTION
00D2E7A0  FF9200010000  CALL DWORD PTR [EDX+$00000100]
00D2E7A6  8BD8          MOV  EBX, EAX
00D2E7A8  8B45FC        MOV  EAX, [EBP-4]
00D2E7AB  8B80B0030000  MOV  EAX, [EAX+$000003B0]
00D2E7B1  8B80B4020000  MOV  EAX, [EAX+$000002B4]
00D2E7B7  E8282B95FF    CALL -$6AD4D8                   ; ($006812E4) Vcl.TListItems.GetCount
00D2E7BC  48            DEC  EAX
00D2E7BD  3BD8          CMP  EBX, EAX
00D2E7BF  7D17          JGE  +$17                       ; ($00D2E7D8) Unit1.TForm1.UpdateGUI (Line=1808)
00D2E7C1  8B45FC        MOV  EAX, [EBP-4]
00D2E7C4  8B80B0030000  MOV  EAX, [EAX+$000003B0]
00D2E7CA  8B80B4020000  MOV  EAX, [EAX+$000002B4]
00D2E7D0  E80F2B95FF    CALL -$6AD4F1                   ; ($006812E4) Vcl.TListItems.GetCount
00D2E7D5  48            DEC  EAX
00D2E7D6  7F04          JG   +4                         ; ($00D2E7DC) Unit1.TForm1.UpdateGUI (Line=1808)
00D2E7D8  33D2          XOR  EDX, EDX

Registers:
-----------------------------
EAX: 00000000   EDI: 0018FABC
EBX: 00D2C96F   ESI: 00000000
ECX: 0018FAB0   EBP: 0018FAC0
EDX: 00000000   ESP: 0018FAB8
EIP: 00D2E79E   FLG: 00010246
EXP: 00D2E79E   STK: 0018FAC0

Stack:               Memory Dump:
------------------   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
0018FAFC: 0018FB28   00D2E79E: 8B 10 FF 92 00 01 00 00 8B D8 8B 45 FC 8B 80 B0  ...........E....
0018FAF8: 04641BC0   00D2E7AE: 03 00 00 8B 80 B4 02 00 00 E8 28 2B 95 FF 48 3B  ..........(+..H;
0018FAF4: 06091090   00D2E7BE: D8 7D 17 8B 45 FC 8B 80 B0 03 00 00 8B 80 B4 02  .}..E...........
0018FAF0: 0878A920   00D2E7CE: 00 00 E8 0F 2B 95 FF 48 7F 04 33 D2 EB 02 B2 01  ....+..H..3.....
0018FAEC: 00000000   00D2E7DE: 8B 45 FC 8B 80 58 04 00 00 8B 08 FF 91 80 00 00  .E...X..........
0018FAE8: 00000000   00D2E7EE: 00 8B 45 FC 8B 80 B0 03 00 00 8B 10 FF 92 00 01  ..E.............
0018FAE4: 00000000   00D2E7FE: 00 00 85 C0 7E 17 8B 45 FC 8B 80 B0 03 00 00 8B  ....~..E........
0018FAE0: 00000000   00D2E80E: 80 B4 02 00 00 E8 CC 2A 95 FF 48 7F 04 33 D2 EB  .......*..H..3..
0018FADC: 0878A920   00D2E81E: 02 B2 01 8B 45 FC 8B 80 5C 04 00 00 8B 08 FF 91  ....E...\.......
0018FAD8: 0091D1DC   00D2E82E: 80 00 00 00 8B 45 FC 8B 80 B0 03 00 00 8B 10 FF  .....E..........
0018FAD4: 08EEACA0   00D2E83E: 92 00 01 00 00 8B D8 8B 45 FC 8B 80 B0 03 00 00  ........E.......
0018FAD0: 0018FAFC   00D2E84E: 8B 80 B4 02 00 00 E8 8B 2A 95 FF 48 3B D8 7D 17  ........*..H;.}.
0018FACC: 0040A4CC   00D2E85E: 8B 45 FC 8B 80 B0 03 00 00 8B 80 B4 02 00 00 E8  .E..............
0018FAC8: 0018FB0C   00D2E86E: 72 2A 95 FF 48 7F 04 33 D2 EB 02 B2 01 8B 45 FC  r*..H..3......E.
0018FAC4: 00D2CB35   00D2E87E: 8B 80 60 04 00 00 8B 08 FF 51 50 8B 45 FC 8B 80  ..`......QP.E...
0018FAC0: 0018FAFC   00D2E88E: B0 03 00 00 8B 10 FF 92 00 01 00 00 85 C0 7E 17  ..............~.
```

Comment: Is `ListViewLayers1` a valid object pointer to begin with? You cannot access the `Items` if `ListViewLayers1` is not valid.

Comment: ListViewLayers1 is on the same form as the call created at design time .

Comment: When I try if ListViewLayers1.Items.Count > 0 then
    ListViewLayers1.Clear; Count is inaccessible.

Comment: Why do you *bother* checking whether the list view is empty before calling `Clear`? If it's already empty, then `Clear` will return quickly. If it's not already empty, then you want to call `Clear` anyway, so just call it without checking.

Comment: Why do people want to close this question? Didn't we all run into a similar problem at some point? Why not help this guy to understand the problem and to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the error is an access violation relating to the code that we can see, the only pointer dereferences in the `if` statement are when you dereference `Self`, and when you subsequently dereference `ListViewLayers1`. So, the conclusion is that either you called the method on an invalid object instance, or that `ListViewLayers1` is an invalid object instance.

If the exception is not such an access violation, then it is an exception raised by the getter for the `Items` property.

Without any more code, or the actual exception details, it is difficult to say any more.

Comment: The strange thing is the ListView is on a DevelopersExpress DockPanel created at design time.  When the call is made, the ListView is visible and empty.  I can add items to the ListView and delete items from the listview but for some reason Assigned produces an exception even though the ListView is a valid object when the call is made.

Comment: I don't think I can say very much more given the dearth of information. I don't know why you kept the details of the exception hidden from us.

Comment: See my edit.  Same question more info. How can an object created at design time not be accessible... never seen this before.

Comment: Not really any more info. I don't know of any `EAccessException`. You need to be precise and accurate here. Copy the error message, the full error message, verbatim. Use the clipboard. Include all the gory details including any hex addresses. Do make use of your debugger to help track errors down. madExcept never hurts either.

Comment: It's a read of a `nil` pointer. Either `Self` or `ListViewLayers1` is nil.

Comment: There is no code in the entire app that free the ListViewLayers1 and the ListViewLayers1 was created at design time so I wonder how the pointer can be nil?

Comment: ok I found the guilty party.  I was wrong... the listview had a free which I did not expect. It should have been Clear.. not Free.. oh My god... what a dummy I am.

Comment: Anyway, you don't need to ask if the `Items` property field is assigned. It should be assigned during the lifetime of the component. I don't know how about Delphi XE4, but in Delphi 2009, the `Items` property cannot ever be set to `nil`. You'd get the `Cannot assign a nil to a TListItems` error message.

Comment: @TLama I guess that test was added whilst trying to debug this problem

Answer (score 0):

When you close a devexpress dockpanel, the default behaviour is that it gets destroyed. That will destroy your listview too, so if you try to access it after that, you'll get an exception.

So, make sure to check if `listviewlayers1` is assigned before you try to do anything with its items. I don't even think you'll have to check if its items property is assigned, unless you're doing some weird hacks to your listview.